# Bounds for prime counting function

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

The prime counting function $\pi(x)$ is defined as

\begin{equation}
\pi(x)=\sum_{p\leq x}1
\end{equation}

where $p$ runs over primes.
I have seen many bounds for $\pi(x)$ such as

\begin{equation}
\frac{x}{\log x}\left(1+\frac{1}{2\log x}\right)<\pi(x)<\frac{x}{\log x}\left(1+\frac{3}{2\log x}\right)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{x}{\log x - 1/2}<\pi(x)<\frac{x}{\log x + 3/2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{x}{\log x+2}<\pi(x)<\frac{x}{\log x - 4}
\end{equation}

Till now, what are the best known upper and lower bounds for the prime-counting function? Is there a better bound that $\mathrm{Li}(x)$?

Comment: Some better bounds are [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Non-asymptotic_bounds_on_the_prime-counting_function)

Comment: ${\rm Li}(x)$ is neither an upper bound nor a lower bound for $\pi(x)$, so it's not clear to me how you can call it a bound. Maybe what you want is $f(x)$ such that $|f(x)-\pi(x)|<|{\rm Li}(x)-\pi(x)|$ for all $x$, or for all sufficiently large $x$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes, that's what I want.

Comment: $f(x)=\pi(x)$ is the best approximation to $\pi(x)$. A close relative is $f(x)=\pi(x)+1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: It is known that $\mathrm{Li}(x)-\pi(x)$ changes sign infinitely often, so it is likely that $\mathrm{Li}(x)=\pi(x)$ holds for infinitely many values $x$ (tending to infinity). If this is the case, then there is no $f(x)$ as in your comment, even when we restrict $x$ to $x>x_0$.

Comment: @GHfromMO Well, $|\mathop{\rm Li}(x)-\pi(x)|\le1$, since $\pi$ is not continuous. But the point still stands.

Comment: mathguy, do you know the prime number theorem with its error term? That will show that functions of the form $\mathop{\rm Li}(x) \pm C x\exp(-c\sqrt{\log x})$ are upper and lower bounds for $\pi(x)$, and explicit values for the constants $C$ and $c$ can be found. This is nearly the best known bound (the power of $\log x$ inside the exponential has been improved). Certainly no bounds of the form $\mathop{\rm Li}(x) \pm Cx^{1-\delta}$ are known.

Comment: @GregMartin: Yes, but $\mathrm{Li}(x)$ is continuous, that is why I only said "likely". If $\mathrm{Li}(x)-\pi(x)$ changes sign in $[n,n+1]$, then there is a chance that $\mathrm{Li}(x)-\pi(x)$ has a zero in $(n,n+1)$. More precisely, $\mathrm{Li}(x)$ only fluctuates about $1/\log n$ on $(n,n+1)$, but there is a chance that, once in a while, $\mathrm{Li}(n)-\pi(n)$ is $o(1/\log n)$ for $n$ as above.

Comment: @mathguy: In my response below, I added some explicit bounds of the type Greg Martin mentioned. Check them out!

Comment: The second bound in the display in the body of the question is a worry, since $x/(\log x-(1/2))>x/(\log x+(3/2))$.

Comment: If you like my answer, please accept it officially (so that it turns green). Thanks in advance!

Comment: I liked your answer. I forgot to accept it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following explicit version of the Prime Number Theorem was proved by [Trudgian](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11139-014-9656-6):
$$ |\pi(x)-\mathrm{li}(x)|<x e^{-0.39\sqrt{\ln x}},\qquad x\geq 229.\tag{$\ast$}$$
In fact Trudgian's Theorem 2 is somewhat stronger than $(\ast)$, and with Mathematica it is straightforward to extend the validity of $(\ast)$ to $x\geq 2$.