# Conjecture about the density of primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

**Conjecture**

> For any sufficiently large integer $kn$ , the sequence representing
> the number of primes in each block obtained by splitting $kn$ into $k$
> equal blocks, is a strictly decreasing sequence, i.e:

$$\pi\left(n\right)>\pi\left(2n\right)-\pi\left(n\right)>\pi\left(3n\right)-\pi\left(2n\right)\ldots>\pi\left(kn\right)-\pi\left(\left(k-1\right)n\right)$$

**My approach**

For any given $k$, we need to prove that for all sufficiently large $n$, the last block contains less primes than the block before:

$$\underbrace{\pi\left(\left(k-1\right)n\right)-\pi\left(\left(k-2\right)n\right)}_{\text{before last}}>\underbrace{\pi\left(kn\right)-\pi\left(\left(k-1\right)n\right)}_{\text{last}}$$

Let $f( k,n )$ denote the difference between the prime count of before last and last block of $kn$:

$$f\left(k,n\right) = \left(\pi\left(\left(k-1\right)n\right)-\pi\left(\left(k-2\right)n\right)\right)-\left(\pi\left(kn\right)-\pi\left(\left(k-1\right)n\right)\right)$$
$$  =   2\pi\left(\left(k-1\right)n\right)-\pi\left(\left(k-2\right)n\right)-\pi\left(kn\right)$$

Therefore, an equivalent formulation of the conjecture is that $f(k,n)>0$ for any integers $k,n$ with sufficiently large $n$.

***Does anybody have ideas or references on how to prove this?***
$$$$
**Computation of $f( k,n )$**

I made some computation that strongly suggests the conjecture is true, at least for small $k$:

[image]

[image]

**Failing case for small $n$**

Let's take the case $k=2$. We see that the conjecture fails for $n=1,2,4$ & $10$:

[image]

I computed $f( k,n )$ for $2 ≤ k ≤ 30$ with $1 ≤ n ≤ 10^{8}$, in order to find what appears to be the last failing case of each $k$ , after which $f( k,n ) >0$ for all $n$:

[image]

Comment: Prime gaps increases unboundedly(one can see that considering all integers n!+2,....n!+n are composites) is this a consequence of that?

Comment: I think this should follow from the Prime Number Theorem (with error terms).  For example, the explicit version of the PNT mentioned here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373737/bounds-for-prime-counting-function

Comment: Note that the second Hardy Littlewood conjecture is likely false, and it is a statement of a similar flavor https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_conjecture .

Comment: To make sure I understand the order of your quantifiers? One is given an $n$ and then is allowed to choose $k$ based on $n$?

Comment: @JoshuaZ: I agree that this is similar, and yet while I would bet $1000 against $1 that the 2nd Hardy Littlewood conjecture is false, this seems reasonable. Being tied to the beginning rather than floating gives a LOT less flexibility.

Comment: Are you aware, @Charles, that 2nd Hardy-Littlewood (that is, number of primes between $2$ and $n$, inclusive, is at least as great as number of primes between $m+2$ and $m+n$) contradicts the conjecture that if there is no prime $p$ such that every $n$ is congruent, modulo $p$, to (at least) one of $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_r$, then there are infinitely many integers $s$ such that $s+a_1,s+a_2,\dots,s+a_r$ are all prime?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I am, but this is very different: disproving HL2 only requires a small dense block of primes somewhere — which is next to certain, and we can give explicit bounds on where such a block is likely to be found — while this requires it to be tethered to the region by the origin, and lets n be chosen favorably (only k is chosen adversarially). Vastly different.

Comment: @Charles, I must be misunderstanding when you write that you would bet against 2nd Hardy-Littlewood being false. Now that I reread what you wrote, I think you were saying you would bet $1000$ to one that 2HL *is* false, so we are in agreement, and I was just misreading.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The conjecture is true, and it follows from the following form of the Prime Number Theorem:
$$\pi(x)=\frac{x}{\log x}+(1+o(1))\frac{x}{\log^2 x},\qquad x\to\infty.$$
Indeed, this implies for any fixed $m\geq 1$ and sufficiently large $n$ that
$$2\pi(mn)>\pi(mn+n)+\pi(mn-n).$$
Why? We have
\begin{align*}\pi(mn)&=\frac{mn}{\log(mn)}+(1+o(1))\frac{mn}{\log^2(mn)}\\
&=m\frac{n}{\log n}\frac{1}{1+\frac{\log m}{\log n}}+(m+o(1))\frac{n}{\log^2 n}\\
&=m\frac{n}{\log n}+(m-m\log m+o(1))\frac{n}{\log^2 n}.
\end{align*}
Similarly (replacing $m$ by $m-1$ and $m+1$, respectively),
\begin{align*}
\pi(mn+n)&=(m+1)\frac{n}{\log n}+(m+1-(m+1)\log(m+1)+o(1))\frac{n}{\log^2 n},\\
\pi(mn-n)&=(m-1)\frac{n}{\log n}+(m-1-(m-1)\log(m-1)+o(1))\frac{n}{\log^2 n}.
\end{align*}
Here, in case of $m=1$, we understand $(m-1)\log(m-1)$ as zero. It follows that
$$2\pi(mn)-\pi(mn+n)-\pi(mn-n)=(f(m)+o(1))\frac{n}{\log^2 n},$$
where
$$f(m):=(m+1)\log(m+1)+(m-1)\log(m-1)-2m\log m.$$
So we only need to verify that $f(m)$ is positive, that is,
$$(m+1)\log(m+1)+(m-1)\log(m-1)>2m\log m.$$
However, this one is clear, because the function $x\mapsto x\log x$ is strictly convex (its derivative is strictly increasing).

Comment: The way I read the question, OP does not ask that $n$ be sufficiently large, only that $kn$ be sufficiently large. If $n=1$ and $k$ is sufficiently large, then $kn$ is sufficiently large, but what OP wants to conclude is quite false.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: The OP wrote: "For any given $k$, we need to prove that for all sufficiently large $n$, the last block contains less primes than the block before". This is what I proved.

Comment: Gerry Myerson nonetheless has a point, in that the main body of the question should contain all the prerequisites, rather one of them being made clear only in the **My approach** section.

Comment: @YaakovBaruch: I agree.

Comment: First of all, thanks for helping ! I’m trying to figure out if there is really a difference between the “Conjecture” statement and the statement in “My approach”. $k$ represents the number of blocks, while $n$ represents the size of each block. This is why, for a given $k$, I only check the last and before last block, because the differences between the other blocks in the sequence are already covered in the case $k-1, k-2$, etc…

Comment: Should the "conjecture" statement begin with: For any integer $kn$ with sufficiently large $n$ ... ?

Comment: @FrançoisHuppé: The statement should begin with: for fixed $k$ and sufficiently large $n$ etc. More formally: for any integer $k\geq 1$ there exists an integer $N\geq 1$ such that for any integer $n\geq N$ etc.